# How to inverse a statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am designing a stack exchange software and i have this query to retrieve those account name in which my customer has  account

```
SELECT TOP (200) account.account_no, account_type.account_type_id, account_type.account_name, customer.first_name
FROM account 
     INNER JOIN customer ON account.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
     INNER JOIN account_type ON account.account_type = account_type.account_type_id
WHERE (account.customer_id = 2)
```

And now I want to select Those accounts in which my customer don't have account

Comment: Do you realize that you have a top 200 but you haven't provided an order to determine what sorting use to take those 200 rows ?. As you have it, it can be whatever 200 rows the engine can reach first, in whatever order it suits it better.

Comment: Seems great. What's stopping you? Please read [ask].

Comment: `account.customer_id <> 2`? It is not clear for me what you want exactly. Please add some example data with expected result.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` customer with accounts.

Comment: It's simple as this `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id NOT IN(SELECT customer_id FROM account)`, Joining this is useless as you don't have any details related to account for those customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select t.account_type_id from account a 
inner join account_type t ON a.account_type = t.account_type_id
where a.customer_id = 2
```

contains all the `account_type_id`s that you want to exclude. 
So use it with a `NOT IN` clause:

```
select account_type_id, account_name 
from account_type
where account_type_id not in (
  select t.account_type_id from account a 
  inner join account_type t ON a.account_type = t.account_type_id
  where a.customer_id = 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RIGHT JOIN` with `WHERE account.customer_id is null`

```
SELECT TOP(200) account.account_no,
       account_type.account_type_id,
       account_type.account_name,
       customer.first_name
  FROM account
 RIGHT JOIN customer
    ON account.customer_id = customer.customer_id  
 INNER JOIN account_type
    ON account.account_type = account_type.account_type_id
 WHERE account.customer_id is null
```

Comment: it returns empty row which customer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT act.*
FROM account_type act
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM account a
                  WHERE a.account_type = act.account_type AND
                        a.customer_id = 2
                 );
```

Note that the `customer` table is not needed for this.